# Launcher Icon Disappeared

Tags: java, android, android-activity, icons, launcher

I am just learning how to program apps for android, so please bear with me. My original starting activity was called Menu.Java. When I tested the app on my phone, a launcher icon would show up and I could launch the app from it. I decided to add a different Activity for my start up, which is called Login.java. I changed the intents to .MAIN and .LAUNCHER and now my icon won't show up at all. I tried switching it back to the Menu.Java and that worked for a bit (but clicking the icon would load the Menu Activity, and I was wanting the Login Activity loaded), but now that doesn't even work.

EDIT: I have also removed all of the activities from the manifest except the .Login Activity. Did not work.

Here is my Manifest:
    `

```
<application
    android:icon="@+drawable/ic_squirrel"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="com.example.advanced.Login" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.advanced.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.advanced.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.advanced.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.advanced.Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.advanced.SETTINGS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.advanced.InternalStore"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.advanced.INTERNALSTORE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.advanced.Reading"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.advanced.READING" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.advanced.Passing"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.advanced.PASSING" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.advanced.Numbers"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.advanced.NUMBERS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: `<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>` remove another category also edit the android name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.advanced.Login" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.advanced.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here change the `<intent-filter>` to

```
<intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you! I swear I checked that before, but I guess not. It of course solved it in a matter of seconds. Thanks!